# Sort by values of custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

Items in custom attribute 'data-priority' can be: 'high', 'normal', 'low'.

Here I select data for sorting:

```
getSortData: {
  priority: '[data-priority]' // get values of attributes
}
```

And this one to sort:

```
sortBy: 'priority'
```

But I don't want to sort items by values alphabetically - I need to sort items by specific order.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as a value in getSortData as [the docs day](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html) :

```
getSortData: {
  priority: function(item){
    return ["low","normal","high"].indexOf( $(item).attr("data-priority") );
  }
}
```